# IOS Scrollbar missing on Skrollr Parallax Implementation

Tags: javascript, ios, drupal, parallax

I've built a demo site using Skrollr's fixed position parallax code:

http://dev-jfw-sample-parallax-2.gotpantheon.com/

And though scrolling works great on my iPhone, the vertical scrollbar has disappeared --  and I'd like how the scrollbar there to indicate there's additional content.

Now when I look at the Skrollr demo page -- which also uses fixed positioning -- on an iPhone I see a scrollbar:

http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

I'm doing this in Drupal so the content is now nested in multiple divs, is that's what's eliminating the scrollbars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the developer:

There are no scrollbars added by skrollr. Add one yourself, you can easily animate the scrollbar using skrollr.

Take http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/ as an example

```
<div id="scrollbar" data-0="top:0%;margin-top:2px;" data-end="top:100%;margin-top:-52px;"></div>

#scrollbar {position:fixed; right:2px; height:50px; width:6px; background:#444; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6); z-index:300; border-radius:3px;}

.skrollr-desktop #scrollbar {display:none;}
```